# grep a certain column from input file

Tags: bash, grep

I have one file, `file1.txt`, with data formatted like so:

```
EMERGE-3 16218877 0 0 2 -9
EMERGE-3 16230920 0 0 1 -9
EMERGE-8 16220003 0 0 1 -9
EMERGE-9 16231695 16220014 16220010 1 -9
EMERGE-11 16218001 0 0 1 -9
```

I have another file, `file2.txt`, with a list of IDs formatted like:

```
16230920
16220014
16218001
16218877
```

I would like to perform a grep search only on column 2 of `file1.txt`. So, the output of the search would be something like:

`somecommand file1 file2`

```
EMERGE-3 16230920 0 0 1 -9
EMERGE-11 16218001 0 0 1 -9
EMERGE-3 16218877 0 0 2 -9
```

(Notice the line `EMERGE-9 16231695 16220014 16220010 1 -9` was not included in the output). This is the main issue I am having right now. If I perform the command:

`grep -f file2.txt file1.txt`

the output will include the line `EMERGE-9 16231695 16220014 16220010 1 -9` because the ID `16220014` is in the 3rd column of `file1.txt` but I am trying to avoid including this line in the output - i.e I only want to search for the IDs in column 2 of `file1.txt`.

Comment: use awk... here's a resource (http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/)  mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info that'll help you for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($2 in a)' file2.txt  file1.txt
```

Comment: You have rather quickly accrued a fairly substantial amount of reputation here. Perhaps it would be time to start learning how to find suitable duplicates and why posting near-identical answers does not help improve the quality of this site. The DRY principle applies here, too.

Comment: @tripleee, sure sir will try to do so.